# Apple PhotoScroller Sample ... How to comine xib to storyBoard?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, xib

I want to make Image gallery  as a part of my project which depends on storyboard ,, I want to use photo scroller apple sample to do that which depends on an xib file as a UIViewController ,, my question is how to combine this to my storyBoard ? I tried to replace the xib file with a UIViewController on the storyBoard and assign Its class to the class name of the photo scroller and nothing changed !!